# Combining class selectors in compass sprite?

Tags: sprite, compass-sass

I have something like this in my icon.scss:

> $icn-sprite-base-class: ".icn";
>      @import "icn/*.png";
>      @include all-icn-sprites;
>
> .blue-bullet li    { @include icn-sprite(blue-dot); }

The last statement is inspired by the "Selector Control" from http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/ . This will give me this kind of output in my icons.css:

> .icn, .icn-delete, .icn-key, .icn-blue-dot .blue-bullet li {
>      background: url('/images/icn-s55e477a40b.png') no-repeat;
>     }
>
> .icn-blue-dot {
>       background-position: 0 -120px;
>      }
>
> .blue-bullet li {
>       background-position: 0 -120px;
>      }
>      ...

As you can see, the *blue-dot* gets its background-position, the *blue-bullet li* as well. And both have the same background-position. As intended. But is it possible to combine these positions? Let's assume I have far more "special selectors", then my CSS would be way too big. So there has to be a solution for combining identical background-positions. Did I miss something?

So I like to end up with something like:

> .icn-blue-dot,
>      .blue-bullet li {
>        background-position: 0 -120px;
>      }

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> .blue-bullet li { @include icn-sprite(blue-dot); }

You can use

```
.blue-bullet li
{
    @extend .icn-blue-dot;
}
```